# snubber networks confusion

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, snubber

[image]

In "switching power supply handbook" by Keith Billings P2 is supposed to represent leakage inductance and D3 is a catch diode, but i don't get quite right.
What is that diode for? how is it even connected to the leakage winding while this winding physically doesn't exist?
He also said that this diode connects when the voltage at the collector reaches 2VDC but I don't see how would that happen.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a real third winding that catches the unspent energy from the primary inductor. It's not the leakage inductance you believe it to be. Leakage inductance in the primary can create damaging voltages that this third winding attempts to control. There is also a conventional snubber shown in the circuit formed by D1, R1 and C1.

Answer (score 1):

If the catch winding has the same number of turns as the main winding and the coupling is tight the collector volts will indeed reach 2Vcc .There always is some leakage inductance so the real spikes in actual convertor operation can be much greater than 2Vcc.The snubber network reduces these voltage spikes .The best that that snubber can do is 2Vcc .In reality the spikes will be greater than 2Vcc .